# Как сделать, чтобы бот телеграм отправлял случайное изображение из папки

Tags: python, telegram

Вот часть кода:

```
import random
import os

directory = 'easycard/'

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
   if call.data == 'play':
      random_image = random.choice(os.path.join(directory))
      bot.send_photo(call.from_user.id, random_image)
```

В папке easycard лежит несколько фотографий. Если в последней строке написать bot.send_message, то бот присылает название случайной фотографии. Надо, чтобы присылалась фотография.

Comment: https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#message

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы заполучить путь к каждому файлу в папке, используйте **glob**, перечень будет храниться в списке.

```
import glob
import random

print(glob.glob(./Music/*)) #['./Music/14 Amityville (feat. Bizarre).mp3', "./Music/01 Глинка_'Камаринская'.wma", './Music/01 Shape of You (Galantis Remix).mp3', './Music/Wingspan Angel.mp3']
print(random.choice(glob.glob('./Music/*'))) #./Music/01 Глинка_'Камаринская'.wma
```