# как сделать, чтобы бот на aiogram 3.0 отправлял рандомное фото из папки?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

идея заключается в том, что пользователь отправляет фотку котика в бота, он ее сохраняет в папку, а потом бот по команде отправляет рандомную картинку пользователю.
вот как я реализовал функцию по сохранению картинки, она работает:

```
@dp.message(Command('kitty'))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('отправь картинку котика:')

@dp.message()
async def get_img(message: types.document):
     file_info = await bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
     downloaded_file = await bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
     file_name = 'img_' + str(random.randint(1, 100)) + '.jpg'
     file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
     with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
         file.write(downloaded_file.getvalue())
         await message.answer('котик успешно сохранен!')
```

а вот функция, чтобы бот выбирал рандомную картинку из папки (переменная folder_path), и она не работает вообще:

```
@dp.message(Command('photo'))
async def photo(message: types.document):
    image_files = os.listdir(folder_path)
    random_image = random.choice(image_files)
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, random_image), 'rb') as photo:
        await message.reply_photo(photo)
```

вот еще так пытался прислать фото:

```
@dp.message(Command('send_photo'))
async def photo2(message: types.Message):
    photo = open('котики/' + random.choice(os.listdir(folder_path)), 'rb')
    await message.reply(photo)
```

и вот так:

```
@dp.message(Command('send_photo2'))
async def send_photo2(message: types.Document):
    ppphoto = InputFile('airforce1.jpg')
    await message.reply_photo(ppphoto)
```

но ничего не работает. выходит такая ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\motor\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pythonProject1\асинхронный тг-бот.py", line 30, in get_img
    file_info = await bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'
```

то есть ошибка в функции get_img, но она работает и сохраняет картинки в папку.
помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему и реализовать пересыл рандомного фото пользователю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы бот телеграм отправлял случайное изображение из папки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066591/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import glob
sp=glob.glob("/путь к вашей/папке/*")
photo = InputFile(random.choice(sp))
await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo)
```

Comment: все равно появляется ошибка 
file_info = await bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'
может эту функцию объявить перед функцией "get_img"?

Comment: Удалите строку `file_info = await bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)`, зачем она вам?

Comment: ну, эта строка нужна, чтобы скачать изображение с помощью строки `downloaded_file = await bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)`
или это можно сделать как-то по-другому?